# Would an object between 7.5 inched to 8 inches be prohibited as carry on?

Tags: air-travel, airports, airport-security, prohibited-items

I have a Karma Grip for my GoPro and it will be the first time I'm traveling with that in my bag. I usually remove it's head so it would fit better in my bag and I end up with an 8 inches grip (a plastic thing similar to a flashlight) on one side of my bag. The grip is around 7.8 inches and it exactly looks like a flashlight WITHOUT a removable battery. Would this thing be a problem in my bag?

Here is its image:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you shouldn't have an issue with that at all - the battery is not an issue and as its not an over-sized item (it fits in your bag) its fine for transport in the cabin.  You may be asked what it is, and possibly to provide a demonstration, but other than that you should be fine.